# Why aren't fighting highlights shown on sports segments?

Tags: boxing, ufc

When you watch ESPN or the local news's sports, they usually show highlights from games/matches of the day.  If another network broadcasted the game, it usually shows the highlight and credits that network.

However, I noticed for boxing or UFC, they might show a freeze frame shot from the fight but will never show the knockout.  What is the reason for this?  Why are fighting highlights not allowed to be shown during sports segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is the rights which UFC holds to their fights and all the content and instances which take place in the fight. Most major UFC fights are Pay per view or sold commercially. However, UFC [recently contracted with ESPN+](https://www.mmafighting.com/2019/3/19/18272292/ufcs-new-exclusive-pay-per-view-deal-with-espn-explained) to use their streaming service as a PPV option for fans. I doubt this will influence what highlights are shown, however.

In short, they want people to pay to watch the good parts of the fight, such as those knockouts or takedowns.